# Porque se muestra error violación del core?

Tags: c++, matrices

Estoy haciendo un problema en que consiste en resolver una sopa de letras. Nos dan una matriz y una palabras a buscar. De output debe de salir la matriz con las palabras en mayúsculas. Yo he hecho el código y lo compila. Pero al poner los datos me sale violación del core. Espero que alguien me pueda ayudar a encontrar el error.
Aquí dejo el codigo.
Tengo una función que sobrescribe en la matriz principal.
Otra función para comprobar en cada dirección si hay una palabra.
Una función que pasa a mayusculas si se hay una palabra.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

typedef vector< vector<char> > Matrix;

vector <string> pedir_palabras(int palabra){
    vector <string> s (palabra);
    for (int i = 0; i < palabra; ++i){
        cin >> s[i];
    }
    return s;
}



Matrix pedir_sopa(int filas, int columnas){
    Matrix s (filas, vector<char> (columnas));
    for (int i = 0; i < filas; ++i){
    for (int j = 0; j < columnas; ++j){
        cin >> s[i][j];
    }
    
}
return s;
}
bool palabra_presente(const Matrix& a, string palabra, int posX, int posY, int direcX, int direcY){
    int letra_string = 0;
    while(posX < a.size() and posY < a[0].size() and letra_string < palabra.length()){
        if (a[posX][posY] != palabra[letra_string]) return false;
        ++letra_string;
        posX += direcX;
        posY += direcY;
    }
    return letra_string == palabra.length();
}
void Mayusculas (Matrix& a,string palabra, int posX, int posY, int direcX, int direcY){
    for (int i = 0; i < palabra.length(); ++i){
        if (a [posX][posY] >= 'a' and a [posX][posY] <='z'){
            a[posX][posY] = char (int (a[posX][posY])-int('a')+int('A'));
        }
        posX += direcX;
        posY += direcY;
    } 
}
void print_Matriz(Matrix& a, int filas, int columnas){
    for (int i = 0; i < filas; ++i){
    for (int j = 0; j < columnas; ++j){
        if( j == 0)cout << a[i][j];
        else cout << ' ' << a[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl; 
    }
}
void resolver(const Matrix& aux, Matrix matriz,vector<string> peticiones){
for(int k = 0; k < peticiones.size(); ++k){
            for (int i = 0; i < aux.size(); ++i){
                for (int j = 0; i < aux[0].size(); ++j){
                    if (peticiones[k][0] == matriz[i][j]){
                    if (palabra_presente(aux, peticiones[k], i, j, 0, 1)){
                        Mayusculas(matriz, peticiones[k], i, j, 0, 1);
                    }
                    if (palabra_presente(aux, peticiones[k], i, j, 1, 0)){
                        Mayusculas(matriz, peticiones[k], i, j, 1, 0);
                    }
                    if (palabra_presente(aux, peticiones[k], i, j, 1, 1)){
                        Mayusculas(matriz, peticiones[k], i, j, 1, 1);
                    }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
int main(){
    int palabras, filas, columnas;
    while (cin >> palabras >> filas >> columnas){
        Matrix matriz = pedir_sopa (filas, columnas);
        vector<string> peticiones = pedir_palabras(palabras);
        Matrix aux = matriz;
        resolver(aux, matriz, peticiones);
        print_Matriz(matriz, filas, columnas);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Mira, me encantaria ayudarte. Podiras porfavor incluir un ejmplo de la entrada y salida del programa?

Comment: input
5(numero de palabras a buscar) 6(numero de filas en la sopa) 7(numero de columnas en la sopa)
mary george john peter martha
las / solo sirven para mostrar en este comentario el final de cada fila en la sopa
r e m a r y a/ 
x y a t r w q/
j e r e s q s/
o o t d a q d/ 
h v h f h w x/
n i a n d a z/

output
r e M A R Y a/
x y A t r w q/
J e R e s q s/
O O T d a q d/
H v H f h w x/
N i A N d a z/

Comment: Gracias. A la proxima que sepas que puedes [editar tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/414087/edit). Asi se nos hace mas facil a todos.

Comment: Mira, luego de pasarlo por el address sanitzer (buscalo y aprende a usarlo, te ayudara con dolores de cabeza), y meter unos mensajes de debug, llegue a que estas accediendo a memoria que no te toca en la funcion `Mayusculas`. En realidad ya no se mas. Pero te lo deje como problema en una sola funcion, y no todo el programa. Mucha suerte para resolverlo. @Infinity

Comment: Muchas gracias.